# Improve load speed of web page with many images

Tags: images, performance, page-speed, optimization

I own an ecommerce website built with Magento that has many images in the homepage for promotional banners. What is the best way to improve load speed? Reducing the file size sacrifice quality, so is there any other way?

Here are some information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry but speed related questions have been asked many times and you should be able to put together a suitable plan using the [279 questions speed related questions](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=speed+is%3Aquestion) already on the site.

Comment: "4.4 MB / 62 Images" - This is just the home page?! I would have thought 4.4 MB of images could be greatly optimised without really "sacrificing quality"?

Answer (score 1):

Basically there can be lots of problem OR sometime a single issue which slow down your webpage while loading.

You can analyze your site here to get exact issue that why its loading slow :

1 - [Google page speed analyzer tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

2 -  [Gtmetrix page speed analyzer tool](http://gtmetrix.com/)

If you feel that only images are making your site slow then always optimize your sites images before upload.

Good image optimization tools are given below :

[Image optimization tool](https://kraken.io/)

Above tool will help to optimize your image without damage image quality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can reduce the loading time of your website by following these steps.

- Reduce or use less java scripts, or pop up window may be adds.
- Go to the Google page speed tester and find out what are the things which increases your page time loading , after analysis , it shows result, problems and how to fix. If you fix that things , your website speed automatically decreases.
- Do not use inline CSS. Always use External CSS.
  so after doing these steps you find your solution.